# Use ConTeXt with another LuaTeX-based engine?

Tags: context, harftex

I've read that ConTeXt is a TeX format, so it can be used with engines such as XeTeX and LuaTeX (`context` loads LuaTeX by default, btw). I wonder if it is possible to use engines as HarfTeX or LuaHBTeX with ConTeXt, as those support nice font features by using embedded Harfbuzz libraries.

Comment: There is [luatex-harfbuzz](https://github.com/tatzetwerk/luatex-harfbuzz), which claims to work with ConTeXt (but I haven't tried it).

Comment: Doesn't it work with MacTeX? I use TeXLive on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Don't know if there are any mac specific components, but it looks like it should work with TeXLive on Linux.